# Is my model overfitting? The validation loss keeps on fluctuating

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I have trained a 4 layer neural network

```
model = Sequential()

#get number of columns in training data
n_cols = X_train.shape[1]

#add model layers
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_cols,)))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate = 0.05))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(1))
#adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae')
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs= 200, validation_split=0.2, batch_size=128)
```

When I plot the graph between train and validation loss the graph seems to be like [image]
The validation loss is fluctuating. Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overfitting is a situation when model starts to perform more better on training set than on validation (example of such behaviour: loss curves are moving to different ways). According to your plot the model hasn't overfitted. Validation loss seems to fluctuating more than train, because you have more points in training dataset and errors on test have higher influence while loss is calculated.

Comment: So, do you mean to say the fluctuation of validation loss is normal here?

Comment: Yes, it's normal behaviour.